# Nextjs JSX and 11ty Nunjucks compare loop with component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nunjucks, eleventy

Blogs Data. And in `11ty`, I already have **blogsData.json** file in **_data** folder.

```
[
  {
    "date": "July 15, 2021", 
    "title": "Ab nihil non sequi.",
    ...
  },
  {
    "date": "July 11, 2021", 
    "title": "Lorem, ipsum.",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Nextjs - React - **pages/index.jsx**

```
import BlogCard from './BlogCard'

export default function HomePage(){

  return <>
    {blogsData.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <BlogCard {...item} />
      </div>
    ))}
  </>
}
```

11ty - Nunjucks - **index.njk**

```
{% for item in blogsData %}
  <div>
    {% include 'blogCard.njk' %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm new to `11ty` and coding Nunjucks, this what I've tried.

But not really get the idea about passing props like above that using in `Next.js`.

Is it possible to do in `11ty` ?

by the way code in **blogCard.njk** in **_includes** folder look like.

```
---
??
---

<h3>
  {{ title }}
</h3>
<p>
  {{ date }}
</p>
```

I think `??` only way passing variables, but how?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are asking. Could you clarify?

Comment: Thank you for coming. You see this `{% include 'blogCard.njk' %}` within `for loop` right? But when it generates the code from `blogCard.njk` will always be the same, in reality it should be the value from `item in blogsData`. I kinda fixed by duplicate the code. Is there a way to do in `11ty`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using item.title and item.date?

Comment: Wait in the separated file from `index.njk` , then inside `blogCard.njk` I just write `{{ item.title }}`, don't I? So much easier than I thought. I'll try do that.

Comment: Let me know if it works - fyi currently on honeymoon so may not respond for a while - was just checking SO this morning. :)

Comment: it works! just easy just that. And I learn that inline block variables also go through different files as well. Thank you